# Dual boot Gentoo and ArchLinux using grub

Tags: linux, boot, grub, arch-linux, gentoo

I am trying to experiment with Gentoo, so I resized my ArchLinux Partition to free up some space.

I installed Gentoo on the following partition schema:

```
Model: ATA ST3500411SV (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name                 Flags
 1      1049kB  3146kB  2097kB                  BIOS boot partition  bios_grub
 2      3146kB  16.1GB  16.1GB  linux-swap(v1)  Linux swap
 3      16.1GB  453GB   437GB   btrfs           Linux filesystem
 4      453GB   453GB   134MB   ext2            gentoo-boot
 5      453GB   500GB   47.3GB  ext4            gentoo-root
```

The BIOS boot partition (#1) was populated with grub from ArchLinux.

For the Gentoo installation I followed the instructions in the official handbook, but I skipped the part about configuring the bootloader, thinking that the grub installation from ArchLinux should be able to handle the booting of Gentoo and Arch.

Maybe that is my mistake.

I added the following to the grub-config in Arch-Linux:

**Updated version:**

```
menuentry "Gentoo" {
        insmod ext2
        set root=(hd0,gpt5)
        linux /boot/kernel-genkernel-x86_64-4.12.12-gentoo
        initrd /boot/initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-4.12.12-gentoo
}
```

This is not the original version I added, I changed a few settings trying to narrow in on the problem.

When I boot, the Gentoo entry shows up in the grub list, but when I try to use it, I get the error message that the file for the kernel can't be found.

My main problem is to understand how do I tell grub that the Gentoo root is in gpt5 and the /boot folder is on gpt4.

I also tried to use os-prober, to generate the entry automatically, but I get the same result, the kernel file can't be found.
The grub config uses gpt5 as root and there is no mention of gpt4 with the /boot folder.

Does anyone have any experience with this kind of problem?

Comment: Just checking: that 'gtp4' in the second last line is actually gpt4?  I assume so, coz 'enuentry'  ;-)

Comment: Is the entry for Arch the same as the one you created for Gentoo, but with different files and root?

Comment: @mcalex Oh, very good point. Yeah, that was definitely wrong. I will test later if this fixed it.

Comment: @mcalex Sadly that didn't fix it. The problem is still there, but thank you for finding that, that was a really tricky one :)

Comment: @Nattgew I didn't copy the settings from ArchLinux, I build the entry from stuff out of the grub documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`boot` and `root` are on separate partititons. `boot` is not mounted on the `/boot` directory on the 5th partition at this point. You should change the root setting `set root=(hd0,gpt4)` and remove the `/boot` part on the paths to the kernel and initramfs images:

```
set root=(hd0,gpt4)
linux /kernel-genkernel-x86_64-4.12.12-gentoo
initrd /initramfs-genkernel-x86_64-4.12.12-gentoo
```